# Broken filenames with Ruby when connected to SFTP version 5

Tags: ruby, automation, sftp

While building a new ruby automation script to handle files up and down from an sftp connection I am having trouble extracting filenames. 
Using these same exact methods I have built automated sftp scripts that are actively being used and have not had much trouble, but I can not seem to output the available filenames of files in this sftp setup.

I know the sftp connection is fine as I am able to upload files and can hardcode in path/filename to download files. 
My problem seems to be specifically with reading the names of the files.

Using typical methods, I can only seem to get output of what appears to be the file object or a mass of jumbled text which does include the filenames:

```
"#<Net::SFTP::Protocol::V04::Name:0x4f6d598 @name=nil, @attributes=#<Net::SFTP::Protocol::V04::Attributes:0x4f6d5c8 @attributes={:type=>1}>>"
```

or (clip from the mass of jumbled(octal?) data that does contain filenames):

```
"#<Net::SFTP::Protocol::V04::Name:0x4f6d778@name="inistrators@BUILTIN\000\000\000\027domain users@POSTNTRACK\000\000\001\200\000\000\000\000X\201\031)\000\000\000\000XE\252\312\000\000\000\000X\201\031)\000\000\000\b\000\000\000\031MVP20170106-238682954.999\000\000\002\275\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\001K\000\000\000\026Administrators@BUILTIN\000\000\000\027domain users@POSTNTRACK\000\000\001\200\000\000\000\000X~z\366\000\000\000\000X~z\366\000\000\000\000Xo\373=\000\000\000\000\000\000\000'MVP20170106-238682954.HTML\000\000\002\275\001\000...."
```

This output is from the code(simplified):

```
require 'net/sftp'
require 'net/ssh'
Net::SSH.start(@site,@user,:password =>@pass) do |session|
session.sftp.connect do |sftp|
sftp.dir.foreach('/Download') do |file|
next if (file.name == '..' || file.name == '.')
next if !file.file?
p file
```

This should be simple but I have been working on this problem for weeks; **please help provide info, point out where I am going wrong, or could this be an issue on the SFTP side?** Have tried with and without SSH session included

Comment: What do you get if you print `file.name`?

Comment: Using print file.name I get jumbled output but looks like it tried to assign chars to the octal code:        'inistrators@BUILTIN   ↨domain users@POSTNTRACK  ☺Ç    Xü↓)    XE¬╩    Xü↓)    ↓20170106-2682954.999  ☻╜☺      ☺K   ▬Administrators@BUILTIN   ↨domain users@POSTNTRACK  ☺Ç    X~z÷    X~z÷    Xo√=       'M20170106-2382954_SUMMARY_5010.HTML  ☻╜☺      0/   ▬Administrators@BUILTIN   ↨domain users@POSTNTRACK  ☺Ç    X~z≈    X~z≈    Xo√>       ↓MVP270111-238912517.999  ☻╜☺      ☺Q   ▬Administrators@BUILTIN   ↨domain users@POSTNTRACK  ☺Ç    X~z÷    X~z÷Xvôt'20170111-238912517_SUMMARY_50.HTML'

Comment: What do you get when you connect using a standalone SFTP client, like WinSCP? - Show us its log.

Comment: Seems fine to login with WinSCP or FileZilla, filenames look good and I can interact fine. Though when I believed this to originally be a permissions issue and asked their support about it they did respond stating 'We have some clients who experienced issues when using WinSCP. '              Log file is available [here](https://file.io/ZmkfsJ)

Comment: I mean log file of WinSCP.

Comment: That is the session level logging from WinSCP of logging into the SFTP in question. Is there a different log you need?

Comment: Sorry never used this quick share file upload, trying again https://file.io/W33QIz

Comment: Do you have an access to server configuration? Can you try to configure the server to use SFTP version 3 at most (not the newer versions)?

Comment: If not, try temporarily changing the `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL_VERSION_SUPPORTED` in `sftp/session.rb` to 3.

Comment: Awesome, yes this did work! I received no unknown characters and I can clearly get the filename which allows me to download all files.

Comment: What did work? The `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL_VERSION_SUPPORTED=3`?

Comment: Yes, I have no access to configure the server as it is 3rd party. Changing the HIGHEST_PROTOCOL.. version solved my issue. Is there any way to change this with this script only? I have a few other scripts that run with sftp and wasn't sure if this would affect them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server implements SFTP version 5. That's rather unusual. Most SFTP servers (OpenSSH in particular) support version 3 only. For that reason newer versions of the protocol are rarely used and it's not uncommon that their implementation is buggy (as not properly tested). What seems to be the case here. The Ruby implementation of the SFTP version 5 is probably wrong.

You can force lower version of the protocol using `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL_VERSION_SUPPORTED=3` in `sftp/session.rb`. It does not seem that there's a way to change the version on a per-session basis. Though, it's unlikely that the change breaks your other sessions, as they most probably use the version 3 anyway.

Comment: Excellent, this has been driving me mad. I will test out my other scripts that use sftp/session.rb just to ensure, but I am confident with your breakdown. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Overriding the constant is no longer necessary as of release 2.1.3rc1 and later, see [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71416517/27358). More details in [Net::SFTP PR #51](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp/pull/51).

Answer (score 1):

Net::SFTP 2.1.3rc1 and later (including 3.0.0, released in 2020) support passing an SFTP version as an option to [`Net::SFTP#start`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-sftp/3.0.0/Net%2FSFTP.start):

```rb
ssh_opts = { password: @pass }
sftp_opts = { version: 3 }

Net::SFTP.start(@site, @user, ssh_opts, sftp_opts) do |sftp|
  sftp.dir.foreach('/Download') do |file|
    # ...
  end
end
```